# How to handle null listview contents in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Iam displaying DB table contents by using a listview.But my issue is that exception was throw when the listview is empty.How can i solve this?

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var tbl = GetAlldealdet();
            ListView1.DataSource = tbl;
            ListView1.DataBind();

        }
     }

  public static DataTable GetAlldealdet()
    {
        try
        {
          string connString = "Server=localhost;database=mytable;uid=root;";
          string query = "SELECT * FROM 'mytable'.'dealmaster' ";
          MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
          DataSet DS = new DataSet();
          ma.Fill(DS);
          return DS.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u return dataset DS ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
   var tbl = GetAlldealdet();
   if (tbl != null) {
       ListView1.DataSource = tbl;
       ListView1.DataBind();
   }
   else {
       //do the logic if empty
   }
```